# How to extract a specific value from Json response and use this value in the input payload json file in Rest Assured Automation Testing

Tags: api, web-services, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am not using any POJO Classes. Instead i am using External json file as payload file for 2 of my API's (Get API and Delete API).

Add API >> Adds the book name, book shelf, other book details along with unique place_id.
Delete API >> Used to delete a book from specific rack using the unique place_id from above.

Since I am using external json payload input file, please let me know the way to pass the "place_id" grabbed from GET API and send this place_id to DELETE API external json file and then use it

**Add Place API below**: This API returns unique Place_ID in the response

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": -38.383494,
    "lng": 33.427362
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Frontline house 1",
  "phone_number": "(+91) 983 893 3937",
  "address": "2951, side layout, cohen 09",
  "types": [
    "shoe park",
    "shop"
  ],
  "website": "http://google.com",
  "language": "French-IN"
}
```

**Delete Place API below**:

```
{
  "place_id": "<need to insert place_id from above response>"
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Added the API details above. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using json-simple library in java. [json-simple maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

imports

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
```

You have to get to the following;

1. Retrieve place_id from Add Place API json response
2. Read request body of Delete Place API from json file
3. Replace the place_id value in request body of Delete Place API
4. Write the new request body to Delete Place API json file

   ```
   // Retrieve place_id from Add Place API json response
   Response response = RestAssured
           .when()
           .get("add_place_api_url")
           .then()
           .extract()
           .response();

   JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();

   String placeId = jsonPath.get("place_id");

   // Read request body of Delete Place API from json file
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
   try {
       Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path/DeletePlaceRequestBody.json"));

       jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

       // Replace the place_id value in request body of Delete Place API
       jsonObject.replace("place_id", placeId);

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   // Write the new request body to Delete Place API json file
   try {
       FileWriter file = new FileWriter("DeletePlaceRequestBody.json");
       file.write(jsonObject.toString());

       file.flush();
       file.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```